# MongoDb aggregate addField if an array of object contains object with specific attribute

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to add a `completed` attribute using addField aggregate query, if the `orders` array inside a collection (`sales`) contains an object with `status` attribute having value `delivered`.

```
db.sales.insertMany([
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "salesId" : "2938432",
        "customerId" : "987677789",
        "amount:"23000"
        "orders":[{
            orderId:"TX8383428979382",
            status:"cancelled"
        },
        {
            orderId:"TX8383428979383",
            status:"fullfilled"
        }]
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "salesId" : "2938433",
        "customerId" : "987676578",
        "amount:"13000"
        "orders":[
        {
            orderId:"TX838342892437363",
            status:"placed"
        }]
    },
    .........
)]
```

My aggregate query

```
db.sales.aggregate([
  {$match:{....}},
  {$addFields:{
    completed: {
                 $cond: { if: { /* code to check if orders array contains an object with `status:fullfilled` }, then: true, else: false }
               }
  }},
])
```

How can I check for a match for an attribute inside array of objects.?

Comment: You can use the [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) aggregation operator with the `$addFields` stage. `$map` will let you iterate over the `orders` array and you can check each element of the array for the condition and add a new attribute when there is match.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_. Seems like i can $reduce also. But I am unable to put it to code. Would be really helpful if u can put an example

Comment: Where do you want to add the `completed` attribute? For the "orders" sub-document _or_ the root/top level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the aggregation which uses the `$reduce` array operator to add a new attribute `completed` which is derived based upon the `orders.status` "delivered".

```
db.sales.aggregate( [
{
    $addFields: {
        completed: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$orders", initialValue: false,
                in: {
                     $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.status", "delivered" ] }, 
                                true, 
                                "$$value"
                     ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
] ).pretty()
```